# JQuery adding slashes to user input (textarea)

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a user profile that updates into a database using JQuery Post and I've just noticed that if I use the word can't in the textarea it uploads to the database as can/'t and reads that back on the profile. My request in the php looks like this:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["name"]);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["location"]);
$about = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["about"]);
```

So is there anything I can add to prevent a slash being added?

Comment: google for magic quotes. the only reasons for the extra slashes in the input are magic quotes or your own code adding slashes.

Comment: Hasn't that been depreciated?

Comment: Anyway, this question as among most duplicated on this site.

Comment: if you are using prepared statements as it was suggested in the other answer, do not use mysqli_real_escape_string then

Comment: I'm not using Prepared Statements at this time as the rest of the site doesn't use it

Answer (score -1):

As other people already said in the comments it's all because of magic quotes:

[Disabling Magic Quotes - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

If you can't disable them and do not want to change your code you can insert this snippet in your files.

```
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
      $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
  }
```

Comment: This code will strip all slashes added automatically by the magic quotes function. You have to insert it before using those global arrays. If that is exactly what you have done and it didn't work then it is not caused by this function. You should check your server configuration, because I simply can't tell you if magic quotes are on just by looking at this snippet you posted. Furthermore you really should disable magic qoutes. [Here is an explanation why.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

Comment: I didn't down vote you and none of the answers I read previously helped me out so I posted this that was specific to my problem - Magic Quotes are turned on in my server so I will try to disable them with htaccess

Comment: Yeah I'm surprised too as it seems like a legitimate answer although it didn't work for me - I went with a simple htaccess command - php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off - Which sorted it out no problem